# Why is Map slower than Dictionary on reads, in F# (from the benchmark I have attached)

Tags: performance, dictionary, f#, containers

I stumbled across this page: http://jackfoxy.com/simple-lookups-in-fsharp/

It benchmarks various collections for insertion and retrieval.

If we look at this table (the second on the web page):

```
String Key by Number of Elements in Lookup Structure, 10,000 random lookups
        Map     IntMap  Dict    HashTbl     HshMltMap
10^2    1.3     n/a     0.4     0.3     1.5
10^3    1.7     n/a     0.4     0.4     1.5
10^4    3.0     n/a     0.7     0.7     1.8
10^5    5.3     n/a     1.5     1.2     2.4
10^6    8.4     n/a     1.6     1.5     6.3
```

We can see that the lookup with a Map is 5x slower than the Dictionary when it becomes large.

Since Map is read-only and has therefore all the luxury to organize the data in the most optimal way as it doesn't deal with insertions, resizing, etc.. why is it so much slower?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [F#: Difference between Dictionary, Hashtable and Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077352/f-difference-between-dictionary-hashtable-and-map)

Comment: @glennsl, not really because the statement in that post that says: 'a Map is as good a choice as any, its immutabil­ity in this case ensures that the sta­tic data can­not be mod­i­fied by mis­take and has lit­tle impact to per­for­mance as you never need to mutate it once initialized.' seems to go completely against the benchmark that shows a 5x performance hit. I fail to see any benefit for the map vs the dictionary besides immutability which is more a theoretical benefit than a practical one.

Comment: From my experiments a large part of the slowness of Map comes from the use of `GenericComparer` which is very smart in that it can compare any value. The problem is that `GenericComparer` because of this is very slow. There has been work by @manofstick to improve performance of `GenericComparer` but that was never merged IIRC. I once proposed the ability to pass a custom comparer to `Map` but it turns out that isn't very easy to get right and intuitive. https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L827

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# Dictionary is implemented using hash tables thus speed of lookup is closed to `O(1)`.

F# Map, due to the immutability, must use binary trees thus speed of lookup is `O(logN)`.

F# Map, and other immutable data structures, actually deal with insertions. You still need to insert an element to a map, but get a new map, and the old map is still intact. To make this effective, the new one and the old one must share elements (no cloning/duplicating involved).

And yes, the best way to do that is using trees (F# Map, Set) or linked lists (F# List).